# FormFunction and Program Input

Tags: input, form-building

I am trying to run a little program on the cloud where users have to supply some input - numbers. I wrote

`enter code here` formShort =
FormFunction[
FormObject[{{"LSize", "Indicate the size of the forest in ha."} -> "Number",
{"BurntHa", "Indicate the average number of ha. burnt per year"} -> "Number" }]]`enter code here`

After executing formShort locally (cloud deploy comes later) and
fill the form for example with 2 and 3 I get something that looks
like an association but I cannot assess the values and therefore
I have no values for the program. What is missing in the code or is
FormFunction not the right approach. Thanks a lot  Renan

Comment: Please clarify your question. There are several issues: (1) You're missing a quote mark, (2) `formShort` is not provided, (3) if I run this, `FormFunction[FormObject[{{"LSize", "Indicate the size of the forest in ha."} -> "Number", {"BurntHa", "Indicate the average number of ha.burnt per year"} -> "Number" }]][]`, I get a valid form, and if I fill it out and submit it, I get a valid association.

Answer (score 2):

`FormFunction` accepts a function and it has access to the values entered. E.g.

```
FormFunction[
 FormObject[{{"LSize", "Indicate the size of the forest in ha."} -> 
    "Number", {"BurntHa", 
     "Indicate the average number of ha.burnt per year"} -> 
    "Number" }], #BurntHa/#LSize &]
```

Comment: After running this code and ask  ``  ?LSize `` I get that the variable is a global value but no value is assigned

Comment: The value will not be assigned unless it is explicitly done in the function. E.g. `LSize = #LSize&`. But there is no reason to do that and pollute the global namespace, the function should perform whatever computation is required using the values and return the desired result for display in the form.